# Problem with updating and unlinking old image PHP

Tags: php, image, file, upload

So problem is that I created 2 methods to set files and check the image if there is an image in tmp, it should delete the old image before moving a new one. But when I upload an image, unlink gives an error like this *unlink(\Users\Murat\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\new\usersimages\42\1593769114256123131.jpg): No such file or directory in* this number belongs to what I uploaded not the old image.

It moves a new image to the folder and try to delete new image but not delete old. this is the main problem. Probably I do a mistake but can't find where. The codes are below.

```
public function set_file($file){
            $this->image = basename($file['name']);
            $this->tmp_path = $file['tmp_name'];
            $this->type     = $file['type'];
            $this->size     = $file['size'];
            $this->image = preg_replace('#[^a-z.0-9]#i', '', $this->image);
            $kaboom = explode(".", $this->image); // Split file name into an array using the dot
            $fileExt = end($kaboom); // Now target the last array element to get the file extension
            $this->image = time().rand().".".$fileExt;

    }

public function checkPhoto($user_id){
        global $database;

    if(!empty($this->tmp_path)) {
        $path = $this->upload_directory.$user_id.DS.$this->image; 
        unlink($path);
        move_uploaded_file($this->tmp_path, 
        $path);
        // unlink("album_uploads/$this->image");
    } elseif (empty($this->tmp_path)) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = :user_id ";
        $query =$database->query($sql, [':user_id'=>$user_id]);
        $row = $query->fetch();
        $this->image = $row['image'];
        $this->type = $row['type'];
        $this->size = $row['size'];
    } else {
        $this->errors[] = "Unexpected error please try again after refresh the page!";
    }
}
```

Comment: if you use `move_uploaded_file`  you can't unlink same file because you move that.

Comment: I'm trying to unlink the old one. not the same file

Comment: I dont see right away the problem, but always use `file_exist()` to check if the file exist on the server and then do the unlink. Always do checks to make sure users never see any of these messages

Comment: I solved it this way  `    if($_FILES['filename']['name']!='') { $albumclass->remove_image(); }`

Answer (score 1):

So I added this part in the checkphoto method and it works now. if I did a mistake please let me know who can have more knowledge.

```
public function checkPhoto($user_id){
    global $database;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = :user_id ";
        $query =$database->query($sql, [':user_id'=>$user_id]);
        $row = $query->fetch();

        $path = $this->upload_directory.$user_id.DS; 
        
    if(!empty($this->tmp_path)) {
        $this->image = $row['image'];
        if (file_exists($this->image)) {
            unlink($path.$this->image);
        }
        // unlink("album_uploads/$this->image");
    } elseif (empty($this->tmp_path)) {   
        $this->image = $row['image'];
        $this->type = $row['type'];
        $this->size = $row['size'];
    } else {
        $this->errors[] = "Unexpected error please try again after refresh the page!";
    }
}
```